# pattern match and create multiple files LINUX

Tags: unix

I have a pipe delimited file with over 20M rows. In 4th column I have a date field. I have to take the partial value (YYYYMM) from the date field and write the matching data to a new file appending it to file name. Thanks for all your inputs.

```
Inputfile.txt
XX|1234|PROCEDURES|20160101|RC
XY|1634|PROCEDURES|20160115|RC
XM|1245|CODES|20170124|RC
XZ|1256|CODES|20170228|RC

OutputFile_201601.txt
XX|1234|PROCEDURES|20160101|RC
XY|1634|PROCEDURES|20160115|RC

OutputFile_201701.txt
XM|1245|CODES|20170124|RC

OutputFile_201702.txt
XZ|1256|CODES|20170228|RC
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
$ awk -F\| '{f="outputfile_" substr($4,1,6) ".txt"; print >> f ; close (f)}' file
$ ls outputfile_201*
outputfile_201601.txt  outputfile_201701.txt  outputfile_201702.txt
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -F\| '                               # pipe as delimiter
{
    f="outputfile_" substr($4,1,6) ".txt"  # form output filename
    print >> f                             # append record to file
    close(f)                               # close output file 
}' file
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution and explaining each step in detail. Awk is simply amazing. Just curious; is it possible to take out that 4th column from the output file when we split?

Comment: Sure. You just have to define the `-v OFS='|'` and `print $1,$2,$3,$5 >> f`